# How to assign json dictionary to NSDictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsurlconnection

I want to do simple SOAP web service calling in swift and assign the response to a `NSDictionary`

```
//Making Connection
    let stringURL="http://www.xxxxx.com/mobileapp/category.php"
    let url1: NSURL = NSURL(string: stringURL )!
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url1)
    let connection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()
```

But I don't have clear idea how to write connection delegates in swift
What should I write under these delegates?

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!)
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
```

My Response is a Dictionary. How can I assign it to NSDictionary in my app side?
Please help me.

Comment: NSURLConnection is deprecated. A nice way is to use NSURLSession instead. Simple example without using delegates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808605/2227743

Comment: wow thank you so much. nicely working