# How to change an NSData to an NSDictionary or JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdata

I have a swift app that calls api and recieves back a JSON.

```
    self.get(url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        self.notify(FetchCompletion, response: response.response, result: response.result)
        print("response: ")
        print(response.response)
        print("data: ")
        let dataExample = response.data
        print(dataExample)
        let dictionary:NSDictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataExample!)! as? NSDictionary
    }
```

And it prints out:

```
...
data: 
Optional(<7b227374 61747573 223a2234 3034222c 22657272 6f72223a 224e6f74 20466f75 6e64227d>)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I want to just print out the data is some readable form by converting to a dictionary.

**EDIT 1**

My get() function is defined as such:

```
func get(path: String) -> Request {

    return self.get(path, data: NSDictionary())
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I am using

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
```

**EDIT 3**

I attempted to follow the example here:[How to parse JSON in Swift using NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805045/how-to-parse-json-in-swift-using-nsurlsession)

But get the error "unresolved identifier 'JSONSerialization'"

**EDIT 4 / probable answer**

```
var newdata = JSON(data: dataExample!)
print(newdata)
```

outputted:

```
{
  "status" : "404",
  "error" : "Not Found"
}
```

I believe that this is a json and I am properly printing the readable data, so i believe this is the answer. I was led to this by the comment suggesting to use swiftJSON

Comment: use SwiftyJSON - https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: How is `Request` defined?

Comment: Note that your response is `{"status":"404","error":"Not Found"}`. Do not use `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData`, use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data: dataExample options:0)`

Comment: Well, keep going with your print statements.  I would guess that  `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData()` is returning nil.  `let x = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(dataExample!); print(x)`

Comment: SwiftyJSON is cool but you don't *have to* use it, there's JSONSerialization (as Larme hinted). http://stackoverflow.com/a/31073812/2227743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very standard way to convert to JSON from NSData, feel free to ask a question

```
  self.get(url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
            self.notify(FetchCompletion, response: response.response, result: response.result)
            print("response: ")
            print(response.response)
            print("data: ")
            let dataExample = response.data
            print(dataExample)
    do {
           let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataExample!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! NSDictionary


        }
     catch {
        // catch error.
              }
}
```