# How to implement generic do-try-catch block to catch all errors that are thrown on an operation

Tags: ios, error-handling, swift2, try-catch, swift3

In Swift 3.0 , how to implement generic do-try-catch block to catch all errors that are thrown as a result of an operation. Apple documentation says to implement a enumerator of type ErrorType , which lists errors that are thrown. Suppose if we don't know what sort of errors that can be thrown by a operation then how to implement it. Below code is only for illustration purpose. Here i can catch the error but i don't know what causes this error. In objective C, we can get exact reason why error happened but here we only get the information that we have assigned to it.

```
enum AwfulError: ErrorType{
case CannotConvertStringToIntegertype
case general(String)}

func ConvertStringToInt( str : String) throws  -> Int
{
      if (Int(str) != nil) {
          return Int(str)!
      }
      else {
          throw  AwfulError.general("Oops something went wrong")
      }
}

let val = "123a"

do  {
    let intval: Int = try ConvertStringToInt(val)
    print("int value is : \(intval)")
}

catch let error as NSError {
    print("Caught error \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I have found solution to my question.Code structure is listed below.

```
do {
    let str = try NSString(contentsOfFile: "Foo.bar",encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(str)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Below code doesn't work because try expression is returning nil .To throw a error try expression should return a error and not a nil value. Type cast operation is an optional.

```
do {
    let intval  = try Int("123q")
    print( Int("\(intval)"))
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: You can catch for ErrorType *and* for other types. Example in the code of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31808605/2227743. (appzyourLife's answer also works).

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your enum will work fine in your use-case as you know in advance that response of a request should have a nsdata  and it should be converted to jSon. In my case i don't even know what are possible error that can be thrown from a operation.I want it to be generic one which captures all possible error.

Comment: It's just an example to show you that you can catch defined errors, the ones conforming to ErrorType, *and* catch NSError ones, *the ones you don't know in advance*. :) And you can *also* add a generic catch like appzyourLife's one if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `catch` to catch any kind of error.

```
do {
    try foo()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks appzYourLife. How do you intent to throw an error from foo() ? Please note i would like get a generic response why the operation has failed.

Comment: @Jinil: the function must be defined this way: `func foo() throws { ... }`